# Remove element from nested array

Tags: javascript

I have this data:

```
const pages = [
  [
    {id: 1}, 
    {id:2}
  ],
  [
    {id: 3}, 
    {id:4}
  ],
];
```

What would the best and more efficient way to remove an element from this structure having 2 indexes as params?

e.g. `index1 = 1` and `index2 = 0` will remove `pages[1][0]` and pages will be:

```
const pages = [
  [
    {id: 1}, 
    {id:2}
  ],
  [
    {id:4}
  ],
];
```

Comment: How do you define "best"? What's the metric? "More efficient" than what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array.splice` to remove an item from an array:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or
> replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place. To
> access part of an array without modifying it, see slice().

This is the demo with a function implementing what did you request for:

```js
const pages = [
  [
    {id: 1}, 
    {id:2}
  ],
  [
    {id: 3}, 
    {id:4}
  ],
];

removeItem(1,0);
console.log(pages);

function removeItem(index1, index2){
  pages[index1].splice(index2, 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
  const idx1 = 1;
  const idx2 = 0;
  pages[idx1].splice(idx2, 1);
```